# issue when renaming AppDelegate - build is ok but getting issue looking for AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I created a new project and wanted to rename to the app delegate from AppDelegate to FlickrAppDelegate. I think I renamed in proper places and am able to build but I get the following error:

[image]

It builds ok but obviously don't want this error. If I look in the Build Log, there are no errors.

How do I remove this issue?

thx

**edit #1**
build phases screenshot:
[image]

**edit #2**
added files screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode. I have seen this a lot of times in Xcode 4.3.2. 
Usually it goes away after I quit and restart Xcode. 
Sometimes, force cleaning the build folder via Option+Shift+Command+K works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Build Phases of your Target executable. See if AppDelegate.m is still listed in the Compile Sources section.

Comment: thx - but no it is FlickrAppDelegate.h - will add screenshot to above to just confirm

Answer (score 0):

You probably renamed the AppDelegate.h to FlickrAppDelegate.h also. S you have to change also the import. From

```
#import AppDelegate.h
```

to:

```
#import FlickrAppDelegate.h
```

Btw. nexttime you do rename, you can do it using **refactoring**. This should take care of everything. Simply go to the AppDelegate.m. **Right-click** on the occurence of AppDelegate after @implementation and choose **Refactor ...**. Then choose **Rename...** . Then you can preview all the changes and you will see that it will od everything for you.

Comment: in main.m? - this was done. The app is able to build - just giving me this issue. thx

Comment: @timpone see the edited answer, It will save you trouble at least next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check you main nib file, and make sure that the class of the delegate is your new App delegate class.

Comment: hmm... I don't have a nib file. Literally, just created the project now. Added screenshot above